# UntilSuccessful component to poll http endpoint till condition is met

Tags: mule, mule-component

Polling http endpoint, receiving JSON response, I wish to keep polling till a condition is met.
I have tried `<until-successful failureExpression="#[json:status != 'COMPLETED']" maxRetries="5" secondsBetweenRetries="10" synchronous="true">` but this is giving exception.

Please also let me know if there is another method for my scenario

Comment: What exception? Mule version?

Comment: Failure expression positive when processing event. I am using the latest mule version

Comment: That doesn't look like an exception: can you edit your question and add the full stack trace in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assign the compute value to flow variable and provide condition evaluting the corresponding flow variable.

`<until-successful failureExpression="#[flowVars['testRetryCondition']  != 'COMPLETED']" maxRetries="5" secondsBetweenRetries="10" synchronous="true">
<processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
<http:........./>
 <set-variable variableName="testRetryCondition" value="#[json:status != 'COMPLETED']" doc:name="set-invocation-status"/>
</processor-chain>
</until-successful>`

Comment: Its giving error for `#[flowVars['sStatusMsg']!='COMPLETED' || flowVars['sStatusMsg']!='ERROR']`. Can you help in correcting syntax

Comment: the syntax is correct, can you post the error. i tried with below expression it works for me.for your view i am added the expression. #[flowVars['t1']!='abc' || flowVars['t1']!='xyz' ]