# Until Successful returning an Boolean value in MULE ESB

Tags: mule, esb

I am using an until successful scope for my outbound endpoint. Am getting a proper response but when it comes out of until successful am getting boolean value my flow is given below

```
    <flow name="testFlow1" doc:name="testFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <until-successful maxRetries="5" failureExpression="#[message.inboundProperties['http.status'] != 200]" synchronous="true" doc:name="Until Successful">
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" address="www.example.com" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    </until-successful>
    <logger message="`From outbound #[payload]`" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
</mule>
```

But am getting output in logger as

```
From outbound true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there not sure what could be happening but here is a example run in 3.6.0 and it works properly:

```
 <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="9090" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="objectStore" class="org.mule.util.store.SimpleMemoryObjectStore"/>
    </spring:beans>
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="localhost" port="9090" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
    <flow name="zzzFlow1" >
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-payload value="#['laleros']" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <logger message="*************************** #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <until-successful maxRetries="5" doc:name="Until Successful" synchronous="true">
            <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/t" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        </until-successful>
        <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
        <logger message="*************************** #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>

    <flow name="tFlow1" >
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/t" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
```

Here is the output I'm getting:

```
*******************************************************************************************************
*            - - + APPLICATION + - -            *       - - + DOMAIN + - -       * - - + STATUS + - - *
*******************************************************************************************************
* zzz                                           * default                        * DEPLOYED           *
*******************************************************************************************************

INFO  2015-02-23 14:10:17,540 [[zzz].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: *************************** laleros
INFO  2015-02-23 14:10:17,593 [[zzz].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: laleros
INFO  2015-02-23 14:10:17,670 [[zzz].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: *************************** laleros
```

And just FYI, I reckon you need the transformer after the the http request to serialise the response for it usually returns the stream as payload.

HIH

Comment: Hi in this example you are not giving any failure or back condition

Comment: You're correct but even modifying that and adding conditions like true != false (which will always be true)  and true == false (always false) I don't manage to make it fail in the way you say it's failing :(

Answer (score 0):

your definition of until-successful scope requires additional configuration need to be done.
give glance over the below link

[UntilSuccessful component to poll http endpoint till condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640243/untilsuccessful-component-to-poll-http-endpoint-till-condition-is-met/28648491#28648491)