# Mule ESB simple http request with rollback exception strategy

Tags: http, mule, esb, rollback

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Call an api that doesn't exist
2. Try to redeliver the original request 5 times
3. Print a message when delivery is exhausted

I have the following flow:

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="localhost" port="80" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<flow name="exceptionTestFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <flow-ref name="exceptionTestSubFlow" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
</flow>
<flow name="exceptionTestSubFlow">
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/hello/" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <rollback-exception-strategy doc:name="Rollback Exception Strategy" maxRedeliveryAttempts="5">
        <logger message="redelivering..." level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <on-redelivery-attempts-exceeded>
            <logger message="redelivery exhausted" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        </on-redelivery-attempts-exceeded>
    </rollback-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

But I get the following output:

> ERROR 2015-03-02 14:15:34,820 [[exceptiontest].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.exception.RollbackMessagingExceptionStrategy:
>
> ---
>
> Message               : Response code 404 mapped as failure. Message payload is of type: BufferInputStream
>
> ### Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
>
> Exception stack is:
>   1. Response code 404 mapped as failure. Message payload is of type: BufferInputStream (org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException)
>
> ### org.mule.module.http.internal.request.SuccessStatusCodeValidator:37 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/module/http/internal/request/ResponseValidatorException.html)
>
> Root Exception stack trace:
>   org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException: Response code 404 mapped as failure. Message payload is of type: BufferInputStream
>       at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.SuccessStatusCodeValidator.validate(SuccessStatusCodeValidator.java:37)
>       at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.innerProcess(DefaultHttpRequester.java:202)
>       at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.process(DefaultHttpRequester.java:166)
>       + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
>
> ---
>
> INFO  2015-03-02 14:15:34,820 [[exceptiontest].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: redelivering...
>   ERROR 2015-03-02 14:15:34,822 [[exceptiontest].HTTP_Listener_Configuration.worker.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:
>
> ---
>
> Message               : Response code 404 mapped as failure. Message payload is of type: BufferInputStream
>
> ### Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
>
> Exception stack is:
>   1. Response code 404 mapped as failure. Message payload is of type: BufferInputStream (org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException)
>
> ### org.mule.module.http.internal.request.SuccessStatusCodeValidator:37 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/module/http/internal/request/ResponseValidatorException.html)
>
> Root Exception stack trace:
>   org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException: Response code 404 mapped as failure. Message payload is of type: BufferInputStream
>       at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.SuccessStatusCodeValidator.validate(SuccessStatusCodeValidator.java:37)
>       at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.innerProcess(DefaultHttpRequester.java:202)
>       at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.process(DefaultHttpRequester.java:166)
>       + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
>
> ---

I'm expecting it to try to redeliver 5 times, but it doesn't seem to work. Am I doing something terribly wrong? Many Thanks.

ps I've tried wrapping the sub flow in a transactional block, but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would instead use an [Until Successful Scope](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Until+Successful+Scope) since I believe HTTP does not support redelivery (see the doc for [Rollback Exception Strategy](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Rollback+Exception+Strategy)).

Answer (score 1):

as HTTP call is a stateless object, defining roll back doesn't seems a good option.
Define you required failure condition over until-successful scope and the corresponding retry times seems a good option to achieve your requirement.

for reference
[UntilSuccessful component to poll http endpoint till condition is met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640243/untilsuccessful-component-to-poll-http-endpoint-till-condition-is-met/28648491#28648491)